# fdisk complains "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used."

Tags: hard-drive, arch-linux, gpt

I recently bought two [Western Digital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Digital) (WD) [Easystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Digital#WD_brand) 8 TB external USB drives to [shuck](https://www.howtogeek.com/324769/how-to-get-premium-hard-drives-for-cheap-by-shucking-external-drives/) them and use the WD Red [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) drives internally in my computer ([Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)). The first ended up being a WD White label drive (WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0), and the second was indeed a Red (WD80EFAX-68LHPN0).

I installed the White one and everything appeared to be fine. I copied over close to 5 TB of data without issue, but later I noticed the message about the [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) error when using [GParted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) on another drive I was working on. My data seems accessible so I haven't done anything yet.

Today I installed the Red drive, and I'm getting the exact same error on that drive as well before any partitioning or formatting. I've been searching for solutions and think it has something to do with having a [host protected area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) (HPA), but I don't know how to verify that for certain, or what to do about it if it does. Is this fixable with my data intact on the White drive? I can experiment on the Red drive, but I am not sure what to try.

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
```

Output:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 15628053168 sectors, 7.3 TiB
Model: WDC WD80EMAZ-00W
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 6837F2B2-3A65-4260-B87E-B4682BAEE5FF
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 15628052446
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4029 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048     15628050431   7.3 TiB     0700  WD_8TB

Command (? for help): v

Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside
at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e'
option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition
table's locations.

Identified 1 problems!
```

and..

```
sudo hdparm -N /dev/sdb
```

Output:

```
/dev/sdb:
max sectors   = 15628053168/15628053168, HPA is disabled
```

Comment: So you’re saying the drives still have their factory partitioning, right? It’s simply a manufacturing error then. It’s also not critical at all.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB. Does that mean I just leave them as is? I just noticed in Thunar's properties window it has this message. **"71021 items, totalling 4.5 TB, some contents unreadable"**

Comment: Apparently, “some contents unreadable” refers to filesystem permissions. If you want to verify the integrity of your filesystem, use the appropriate tool: `fsck`.

Comment: My new WD100EMAZ (from an Elements enclosure) produced the same warning. Must be something that WD do with these at the factory. I had yet to write anything to the drive, and I was going to repartition it anyway, so I just created a new GPT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `hdparm` output indicates that HPA is *disabled,* so the issue is unrelated to that.

The most common cause of this problem, judging by similar issues I've seen posted here and on other forums, is the use of motherboard-based software RAID (sometimes called "fake RAID," although that's a deceptive term). The trouble with this type of software RAID is that it requires at least two software components to agree on the data structures to be used -- the firmware and the OS. In the case of a multi-boot computer, all OSes must understand the same RAID data structures, so you'd need three or more configurations to match. In any event, if the firmware thinks that the disk uses motherboard-based software RAID but an OS doesn't, the result is likely to be damage to the backup GPT data structures. The reason is that these data structures occupy the last few sectors of the disk, and this is also exactly where motherboard-based software RAID usually stores *its* data structures. Thus, one set of data structures will wipe out the other. Wackiness ensues. (See below, though.) When everything is in sync, it's transparent; the motherboard puts its data structures at the end of the disk, the OS(es) understands this and hides that part of the disk, and you don't need to worry about it.

If you didn't create the partition table, though, it's possible that the problem is not caused by such a misconfiguration on your part, but rather on the part of the disk's manufacturer, or perhaps somebody who handled the disk in-between (say, if the disk was sold to somebody else and then returned, and you got it from a returns bin). In this case, doing a `w` in `gdisk` should re-write the partition table, causing the error message to go away. Doing this is a good idea, since the GPT backup data structures exist for a reason -- they're a *backup,* to be used in case some types of bugs, user errors, or hardware faults damage the primary data structures (stored at the beginning of the disk). Most OSes and tools will boot fine with the backup data structures missing, but going without them means you're giving up their benefits. Also, there's a chance that some tool will become confused by the damage and do something bad. (I know of no examples of this, but new tools are being written all the time, and old ones can develop new bugs, so the possibility of such a bug is ever-present.)

One more point: `gdisk`'s `v` indicates that the backup partition data does not exist at the end of the disk, where it should. To fix this, you can type `x` to get to the experts' menu, then `e` to relocate the backup data structures. This misplaced backup partition table is consistent with the use of motherboard-based software RAID in the firmware but not by the OS, or with various other issues (like a hardware RAID array that's been expanded or a disk that's been cloned from a smaller to a bigger disk). Relocating the backup data structures is generally a good idea, and in some cases it's necessary to use the disk's full capacity. (In your case, you'll recover only about 2,000 sectors, so it's not a big deal in terms of capacity.) Note, however, that if your motherboard is configured to use its software RAID, moving the backup data structures will wipe out the software RAID data. This might confuse the motherboard, and the motherboard is likely to rewrite its data, causing the GPT to be damaged the next time you reboot. The solution is to disable software RAID options in the firmware setup tool, then move the GPT data structures using `gdisk` or some other tool.

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Both disks accepted the fixes you suggested and survived reboots. I checked my bios and it did have a raid mode option, but was set to AHCI mode. I guess this means both disks did come this way and wasn't caused by my computer. One thing to add is gdisk prompted me to fix the backup partition after writing the primary, so I didn't need to go into the experts menu. Not sure if it was relocated to the end or not, but decided on your programs defaults. Wasn't worried about the extra capacity anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The controller of the WD Easystore enclosures "steals" a small number of blocks at the end of the drive for some reason. The effect of this is that the "end" of the drive changes. If you partition the drive with GPT while it's still in the enclosure, the backup partition table will be written to a location that is not quite the *real* end of the drive, since those stolen blocks are hidden from view.

Once you shuck the drive, the real end of the drive becomes accessible and since the GPT backup isn't there, it looks like a problem. Details are discussed on [a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/ejqdeh/psa_do_not_swap_your_nonempty_drives_into/).

The easiest fix, if there's nothing on the drive, is to repartition with a new GPT. I suppose there are some manual approaches to fixing the issue by manually copying the backup GPT to its correct location, at which point you can decide whether to enlarge the last partition to use the newly accessible space. But since the amount of the change is probably not even 1MB, it might not be worth that.